# Putting if statement inside a method that is supposed to return an int value

Tags: java, conditional-statements, return-value, logical-operators

I'm having trouble implementing my condition via if statement inside a method that is supposed to return an int value at the end. I'm being reminded that you cannot have a boolean inside a method that is supposed to return an int value. Below is the code for context:

```
public int getDayOfWeek (int year, int month, int day) {
    int i1 = 4;
    int i2= 2;
    int i3= 0;
    int i4 = 6;
    if (year => 17 && year =< 18) {
        centuryNum = i1;
        return centuryNum;
    }
    ....
}
```

What is the correct way of implementing a series of if statements inside such a method?

Comment: That's fine if you return something in case the `if` condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to return an int value in this method. In your case the only return statement we can see is within an if condition that might not evaluate to true.

In addition, the if statement itself is not in correct syntax, that could be your problem too. The greater/smaller than sign should come first. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html for how to use these operators. Note that reading the compiler error would have probably helped you with this too.

```
Equality and Relational Operators
==      Equal to
!=      Not equal to
>       Greater than
>=      Greater than or equal to
<       Less than
<=      Less than or equal to
```

Comment: this is pretty much the code. even when I add an else statement after and return another value, the if statement is still not accepted

Comment: I was put on the wrong foot initially with your statement about int/boolean return values, but if you had posted the compiler error it would have made your question a lot more clear.

Answer (score 2):

`year >= 17 && year <= 18` is correct. You'll get a compiler error for `year => 17 && year =< 18`. 
see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html
to learn basic operations.

> Greater than or equal to:     >=
>   Less than or equal to:     <=

Comment: OP has some troubles with returning value from the method.

Comment: It actually does seem to have been the OP's problem, regardless of the way he phrased the question.